# Different output of \ref and \cref in lists with enumitem+cleveref

Tags: hyperref, enumitem, cleveref

I'm using `enumitem` and `cleveref` packages and I would like to enforce a different behaviour of `\ref` and `\cref` for `{enumerate}` lists.

More precisely, whenever I have lists in a theorem environment I add a `label=...` and `ref=...` options to `enumerate` so to include theorem prefix (Thm, Lem, Prop, ...) and corresponding number.
However, in the proof of the theorem I would like to avoid such redundant prefix, and I was hoping to achieve this by specifying different behaviours of `\ref` and `\cref` commands. The problem would be solved if `enumitem` offered a `cref=...` option to `enumerate` environment, which however is not the case.

***EDIT:** I changed the MWE to remove possible ambiguities.*

I'm posting the following MWE hoping that it can help clarify what I want: specifically, (notice the different use of `\ref` and `\cref` for referring to items in the same Theorem being proved or in the *external* Theorem, which, however, are typeset the same) I would like to eliminate the prefix "Thm. 1.2" when referencing the items of the Theorem in its proof.

And yes, everything should be compatible with `hyperref`...

```
\documentclass[english]{amsart}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
% cleveref options for thm
    \crefname{thm}{Thm.}{Thm.}
    \crefformat{thm}{#2Thm. #1#3}
% cleveref options for enumi: remove "item "
\crefformat{enumi}{#2#1#3}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\begin{thm}\label{Thm:One}
The following properties hold:
\begin{enumerate}[{label=(\alph*)},{ref=\cref{Thm:One}(\alph*)}]
    \item\label{Thm:One:1} \(1>0\)
    \item\label{Thm:One:2} \(0<1\)
\end{enumerate}
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}\label{Thm:Two}
The following properties hold:
\begin{enumerate}[{label=(\alph*)},{ref=\cref{Thm:Two}(\alph*)}]
    \item\label{Thm:Two:1} \(2>1\)
    \item\label{Thm:Two:2} \(1<2\)
\end{enumerate}
\begin{proof}
\ref{Thm:Two:1} follows from \cref{Thm:One:1} by adding 1 on both sides and similarly \ref{Thm:Two:2} follows from \cref{Thm:One:2}.
\end{proof}
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

and the output is as follows
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible solution (if I've understood the question correctly).

The key is to use a different `\crefformat` inside `proof` at the begin of the `proof` environment and restoring it back to the old one at the end.

This is achieved by using `\AtBeginEnvironment{proof}{...}` and `\AtEndEnvironment{proof}{...}`

```
\documentclass[english]{amsart}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
% cleveref options for thm
    \crefname{thm}{Thm.}{Thm.}
    \crefformat{thm}{#2Thm. #1#3}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
% cleveref options for lem
\crefname{lem}{Lem.}{Lem.}
\crefformat{lem}{#2Lem. #1#3}
% cleveref options for enumi: remove "item "
\crefformat{enumi}{#2#1#3}

\AtBeginEnvironment{proof}{%
  \crefformat{lem}{#2 #1#3}%
}

\AtEndEnvironment{proof}{%
  \crefformat{lem}{#2Lem. #1#3}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\begin{thm}\label{Thm:One}
The following properties hold:
\begin{enumerate}[{label=(\alph*)},{ref=\cref{Thm:One}(\alph*)}]
    \item\label{Thm:One:1} \(1>0\)
    \item\label{Thm:One:2} \(0<1\)
\end{enumerate}
\end{thm}

\begin{lem}\label{Lem:Two}
  The following properties hold:
  \begin{enumerate}[{label=(\alph*)},{ref=\cref{Lem:Two}(\alph*)}]
  \item\label{Lem:Two:1} \(2>1\)
  \item\label{Lem:Two:2} \(1<2\)
  \end{enumerate}
\begin{proof}
  \ref{Lem:Two:1} follows from \cref{Thm:One:1} by adding 1 on both sides and similarly \ref{Lem:Two:2} follows from \cref{Thm:One:2}.
\end{proof}
\end{lem}

Original reference is: \ref{Lem:Two:1}
\end{document}
```

**Update**

```
\documentclass[english]{amsart}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}



\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
% cleveref options for thm
\crefname{thm}{Thm.}{Thm.}
\crefformat{thm}{#2Thm. #1#3}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
% cleveref options for lem
\crefname{lem}{Lem.}{Lem.}
\crefformat{lem}{#2Lem. #1#3}
% cleveref options for enumi: remove "item "
\crefformat{enumi}{#2#1#3}



\newcommand{\Lemcrefext}[1]{%
 \begingroup
 \crefformat{lem}{##2Lem. ##1##3}
 \cref{#1}%
 \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\Thmcrefext}[1]{%
 \begingroup
 \crefformat{lem}{##2Lem. ##1##3}
 \cref{#1}%
 \endgroup
}


\AtBeginEnvironment{proof}{%
  \crefformat{lem}{#2 #1#3}
}


\AtEndEnvironment{proof}{%
  \crefformat{lem}{#2Lem. #1#3}
}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\begin{thm}\label{Thm:One}
The following properties hold:
\begin{enumerate}[{label=(\alph*)},{ref=\cref{Thm:One}(\alph*)}]
    \item\label{Thm:One:1} \(1>0\)
    \item\label{Thm:One:2} \(0<1\)
\end{enumerate}
\end{thm}

\begin{lem}\label{Lem:Two}
  The following properties hold:
  \begin{enumerate}[{label=(\alph*)},{ref=\cref{Lem:Two}(\alph*)}]
  \item\label{Lem:Two:1} \(2>1\)
  \item\label{Lem:Two:2} \(1<2\)
  \end{enumerate}
\begin{proof}
  \ref{Lem:Two:1}  follows from \cref{Thm:One:1} by adding 1 on both sides and similarly \ref{Lem:Two:2} follows from \cref{Thm:One:2}. However, in \Lemcrefext{Lem:Three} and \Thmcrefext{Thm:One} it will be shown that...
\end{proof}
\end{lem}

\begin{lem}\label{Lem:Three}
Foo
\end{lem}

Original reference is: \ref{Lem:Two:1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @ChristianHupfer for your answer, I think I get it. However, I guess that `\ref`and `\cref` would still behave the same also in `proof` envirinoment. I mean, what if I want to refer to an external Lemma in the proof?

Comment: @AndreasT: Difficult at best, actually ;-)

Comment: I edited the MWE, however other workarounds are also welcome, by possibly defining new commands or whatever. It need not involve different behaviours of `\ref` and `\cref`

Comment: @AndreasT: The easiest solution for referring to an 'external' theorem or lemma is to use another command that explicitly uses the `outer` `\crefformat`, i.e. a wrapper command

Comment: @AndreasT: I've added two small commands that restore the cref format internally. Any other approach would involve label etc. parsing and comparisions, which is not feasible without much ado, actually

Comment: I see, thank you very much! However, we could condensate `\Lemcrefext` and `\Thmcrefext` (and possibly others) with in a single `\crefext` as follows, right?

\newcommand{\crefext}[1]{%

 \begingroup

 \crefformat{lem}{##2Lem. ##1##3}

 \crefformat{thm}{##2Thm. ##1##3}

...
 
\cref{#1}%
 
\endgroup

}

Comment: @AndreasT: Well, that should be possible. I thought you wanted to have separate commands for Thm and Lem... Shall I change my solution?

Comment: I guess yours is just fine, it's me who probably didn't get it completely. I guess I have to test it on some _real_ documents first. Thank you again!

Comment: @AndreasT: You're welcome. Happy TeXing

Comment: +1. Two minor points: (i) LaTeX should be informed that the dot *after* "Thm" and "Lem" isn't of the sentence-ending variety. E.g., change `\crefformat{thm}{#2Thm. #1#3}` to either `\crefformat{thm}{#2Thm.\ #1#3}` or `\crefformat{thm}{#2Thm.~#1#3}`. (I prefer the second form...) (ii) There seems to be spurious space *before* "Lem."; add a `%` character after `\crefformat{lem}{##2Lem.\ ##1##3}` to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that uses (a) `cleveref`'s `\crefalias` device and (b) two dedicated enumeration environments, named `enumthm` and `enumcor`, to be used inside the environments named `thm` and `cor`, respectively. The idea is this allows you to use `\ref` and `\cref` independently -- their outputs will differ only in whether or not a label ("Thm.", "Cor.") will be prefixed to the compound "number" associated with the theorem or corollary being cross-referenced.

By the way, I would use upright rather than italic alphabetic "numbers" -- (a), (b), etc -- for enumerations in theorem-like environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass[english]{amsart}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}  % for '\newlist' and '\setlist' macros
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
%%\usepackage{amsthm}  % is loaded automatically by amsart document class
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\crefname{thm}{Thm.}{Thms.} % singular and plural forms of label

\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\crefname{cor}{Cor.}{Cors.} % singular and plural forms of label

\newlist{enumthm}{enumerate}{1} % set up a dedicated enumeration env.
\setlist[enumthm]{label=\upshape(\alph*),ref=\upshape\thethm(\alph*)}
\crefalias{enumthmi}{thm} % alias 'enumthmi' counter to 'thm'

\newlist{enumcor}{enumerate}{1} % set up a second dedicated enumeration env.
\setlist[enumcor]{label=\upshape(\alph*),ref=\upshape\thecor(\alph*)}
\crefalias{enumcori}{cor} % alias 'enumcori' counter to 'cor'


\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1} % just for this example

\begin{thm}\label{Thm:One}
The following properties hold:
\begin{enumthm}
    \item\label{Thm:One:1} \(1>0\)
    \item\label{Thm:One:2} \(0<1\)
\end{enumthm}
\end{thm}

\begin{cor}\label{Thm:Two}
The following properties hold as well:
\begin{enumcor}
    \item\label{Thm:Two:1} \(2>1\)
    \item\label{Thm:Two:2} \(1<2\)
\end{enumcor}
\begin{proof}
\ref{Thm:Two:1} follows from \ref{Thm:One:1} by adding 1 on both sides. Similarly, \cref{Thm:Two:2} follows from \cref{Thm:One:2}.
\end{proof}
\end{cor}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mico, I got it. I also appreciate the comments and the typographical suggestions :)

Comment: @Mico I have a very similar problem, except that I don’t want the `\ref` output to be “1.2(a)”, but simply “(a)”. Is that possible to achieve in a way that maintains the `\cref` output “Theorem 1.2(a)”?

Comment: @Mico I have now created a separate question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336198/clever-references-to-theorem-lists).